# How to convert intensity (in pixel) to measured values (in mm, for instance) in r

Tags: r

I plot a range of values in mm from `c(-3,3)` using `scale_fill_gradient(low= "black", high = "red")` by `ggplot2` and the plot is analyzed by a another programme. One of measurements is exported as intensity in pixel and I want to convert it back to the values in mm. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is my first ever post! Anyhow this is the hackey solution I've come up with. I've switched from black to red to black to white since we'll only have to deal with 1 pixel value. What I've done is create a plot, convert it to an image and look at the pixel values of 1 row of the plot. The pixel values 1 to 0 (black to white) map onto the initial mm values -3 to 3 after you rescale the range. Just my attempt, hope it helps.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(imager)
range01 <- function(x){(x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))}

dat <- data.frame(mm = seq(-3,3,.1))

####plot them out like you want
plot <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(y=1, x=mm, fill = mm))+
  geom_tile()+
  scale_fill_gradient(low= "black", high = "white")

#There's probably a better way to save the plot and retrieve it as an image
ggsave("plot.jpg", plot)

img <- imager::load.image("plot.jpg") %>% 
  grayscale() %>% #convert to grayscale
  imsub(img, x>300, x <1900) #trim on the left and right

dims <- dim(img2) #get dimensions

values <- img2[,dims[2]/2,,] #Take a single pixel slice out of the image. 0 
is black 1 is white

dat$scaled <- range01(dat$mm) # dat$scaled should correspond to values vector from the plot and you should be about to get mm by matching across.
```